# getting data from realtime database using http package flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

enter image description here

[model named cartitems and its respective i looked up in stackoverflow and took this code and also the code from 2nd img is from stack overflow but got errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFhjx.png)

[from stackoverflow got errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzfe.png)

[structure of data pushed into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo7d1.png)

[i tried to fetch data using http package and it was a success but pushing the same data to other collection in the same database is showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrNSX.png)

above 4 pictures show how i was trying to fetch data from realtime database

Comment: Please link on the above links to view images

Comment: Please add your code in the markdown and not as image

Comment: Also please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.  Please also replace picture of the database with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with and use them in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.